# Twilio + Apple o mach error

Tags: xcode, twilio

When I try to run the code I get an `Apple O-Mach Linker Error`. I'm running up to date XCode 4.6, updated yesterday. I'm running 10.8.2 and here is the error code I get.

A few weeks ago I wasn't getting this issue so I don't know if it's updated SDK from Twilio, the XCode update or what. I've also got one of the library's (`libTwilioClient.a`) thats red in the frameworks section (This is my first iOS and XCode experience). I've tried linking it and then I get 68 errors about other stuff throughout the program not connecting.

Any help? Oh, BTW, I'm just using the HelloMonkey Example from Twilio's SDK, I haven't changed a single thing except the line pointing to my php server for authentication. Also, I've check for any `.m` in the headers and there are none. I was hoping that it would be smooth sailing since it's coming from Twilio and it's the "Get Started Quick"... so much for that :/

```
Ld /Users/Animal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloMonkey-
acqupeuamziuogblpxusdjhityyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloMonkey.app
/HelloMonkey normal i386
    cd "/Users/Animal/Downloads/TwilioClient-1.1.1-dbefc0b/Quick Start/HelloMonkey
"
    setenv IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 4.2
    setenv PATH "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/
iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/
Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.
xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator6.1.sdk
 -L/Users/Animal/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloMonkey-acqupeuamziuo
gblpxusdjhityyf/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator "-L/Users/Animal/Downloads/
TwilioClient-1.1.1-dbefc0b/Quick Start/HelloMonkey/../.." -F/Users/Animal/
Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HelloMonkey-acqupeuamziuogblpxusdjhityyf/
Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -filelist /Users/Animal/Library/Developer/
Xcode/DerivedData/HelloMonkey-acqupeuamziuogblpxusdjhityyf/Build/Intermediates/
HelloMonkey.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloMonkey.build/Objects-normal/i386/
HelloMonkey.LinkFileList -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -ObjC -all_load
 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=4.2
 -framework AVFoundation -framework Foundation -framework UIKit -framework 
CoreGraphics -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework 
SystemConfiguration -lTwilioClient -o /Users/Animal/Library/Developer/Xcode/
DerivedData/HelloMonkey-acqupeuamziuogblpxusdjhityyf/Build/Products/
Debug-iphonesimulator/HelloMonkey.app/HelloMonkey

ld: library not found for -lTwilioClient
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: any solution on this? we're having the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add, other two libraries **libcrypto.a** and **libssl.a** along with **libTwilioClient.a**, then clean and build the project. You are good to go. You can find those libraries in the 'Libraries' folder of the unzipped Twilio bundle. Hope this will help.